# Problem with data comparison in if loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, test

I have 2 variables in bash. Using test i found out that one of them is integer and other one is string. I want to compare them and see if they are equal. I tried the following options.

```
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]

if [[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]]

if [ "$a" = "$b" ]

if [[ "$a" = "$b" ]]
```

I tried converting the string variable to integer as

```
a=$(($a+0))
```

but I got the following error

> +0")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

None of them are providing me the expected result. Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have multiple CSV files. The second field of the last row in each of these files will contain the number of rows in that file. I have to get the row count from the file and compare it against the actual number of rows in the file. If they are same, then only I have to process.

```
ROW_COUNT=`grep -c ^ /tmp/file1.csv` --This is the number

LAST_LINE=`tail -n 1 /tmp/file1.csv`
ACTUAL_ROW_COUNT=`echo ${LAST_LINE} | cut -d "," -f 2` --This is the string

--now i am comparing these two numbers to see if they are same.
if [[ ${ROW_COUNT} == "${ACTUAL_ROW_COUNT}" ]]; then -- Here it is breaking
```

Comment: `-eq` will compare them as integers, `=` will compare them as strings. You don't need to convert the string first.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. What was the original value of `$a`, and what is the exact statement you used?

Comment: What's the difference between your third and fourth options?

Answer (score 0):

The following if statement worked for me.

```
if [[ ${a} = *"${b}"* ]]; then
```

Comment: Why so complicated?  This will report TRUE if `$a` *contains* `$b`; e.g., `a=foo42bar` and `b=42`, or `a=1942` and `b=94`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with (())? it is used for numbers instead of characters. So the comparison would be:

```
 if (( "$a" == "$b" ))
```

Mind the double == it is important.

Comment: I tried this. It did not work for me.

Comment: @stany could you echo the values before the `if`? what values do $a and $b have before the `if` loop?

Comment: i echoed both values. both have same value. In my example, ACTUAL_ROW_COUNT is string. I tried ACTUAL_ROW_COUNT=`expr $ACTUAL_ROW_COUNT + 0` , but it gives me "expr: non-numeric argument" error.

Comment: @stany I must be missing something... Is the problem that ACTUAL_ROW_COUNT sometimes returns a number and sometimes returns a string? in that case, you have to process that variable before you compare it.

Comment: I sort of narrowed down on the problem. the last row of file usually contains ###,749 from this i am extracting the ###,749                                            If i put a , (comma) after 749, it works

Comment: if you awk'd the result getting 749 (`awk -F, '{print $2}'`) it still gives you errors? I don't see the need for that comma.

Comment: finally!!! it had trailing space..so trimmed it...gosh!!

Comment: Weird, if I do a `x="03 "` and after that I do a `echo $(($x+1))` I am returned `4`. I guess what you have after the number is some special character. Anyway, I'm glad you solved it.